# fade in fade out with two divs does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/largan/2n2Lf/25/
The idea is the div called soc_text to fade and fade out when hover on the soc_button div.

I have this script, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $("div.soc_button").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.soc_text").fadeIn('slow');
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.soc_text").fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: As I can see you dont have div.soc in your HTML

Comment: ...and double quotes is missing

Comment: You also didn't include jQuery in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2n2Lf/17/

Comment: @aldanux double quotes where? mixing single and double (albeit ugly and maybe confusing is just fine.  Unless I'm missing something (I looked at the both the first 2 edits available at this point)

Comment: oh, stupid me... I did forget to insert the jQuery script... it works now... but I have a different problem... it doesnt stop fading in and out and it shows the soc_text div while it should be hidden by the css. Also in my example For some reason it stripped the name of the divs... fixed now

Comment: @FlakDiNenno - Yes, is absolutly fine...but hey ... have fun in this way to coding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "div.soc_button", function(){
    $(this).find("div.soc_text").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thats a good solution but see when you mouse over the icons, the text shows behind the icons... **http://jsfiddle.net/largan/2n2Lf/26/**

Comment: the script is showing anything that has been placed in the html and css. If you want to show your hover transitions only, then you do not need the jquery code. everything looks like it displays properly without the script http://jsfiddle.net/2n2Lf/27/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $("div.soc_button img").hover(
    function () {
      console.log();
      $(this).parent().find('div.soc_text').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 
    function () {
      $(this).parent().find('div.soc_text').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  );
});
```

I guess the code is self explanatory,
Regards

Comment: it work... but strangely if the img is a link, then it doesn't.. any ideas ?

Comment: If the image is a link,then the parent() would call the <a> tag.
In that case, you should write parent(), 2 times,ie,

$(document).ready(function () {    
  $("div.soc_button img").hover(
    function () {
      console.log();
      $(this).parent().parent().find('div.soc_text').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 
    function () {
      $(this).parent().parent().find('div.soc_text').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  );
});

Comment: it works, but when you hover the soc_button, the text also appear behind the icons

Answer (score 0):

This applies the method to all matches with all div tags  with soc_text css class

```
 $("div.soc_text").fadeIn('slow');
```

Change this to

```
$(this).children('div.soc_text').fadeIn('slow');
```